# IBrokers Put in an Order at the Mid

Tags: r, trading, ibrokers

I'm playing around with some ideas using R and IBrokers with a paper trading account. I'm looking at making orders through R, but was wondering if there's an easy way to make these orders at the mid price, since I'm not expecting to always buy and sell at the bid and ask.

I believe what I'm looking for is a Pegged-to-Midpoint order (https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=1058). I didn't see this as an order type in the R documentation for the IBrokers package. Does anyone know if this is doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [API documentation pegged midpoint](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/basic_orders.html#pegged_midpoint) the order type should be "PEG MID".

```
placeOrder(twsconn=tws,
            Contract=twsSTK("AAPL"), 
            Order=twsOrder(reqIds(tws),
                           action = "BUY", 
                           totalQuantity = 10, 
                           orderType = "PEG MID"))
```

Note: I have not tested this because it at the moment I have a live session going on.

Comment: I'm probably misinterpreting PEG MID, but when I test out putting orders in with it, they don't seem to actually get filled. The order is recognized in the workstation, so I'm probably misinterpreting its meaning. I would just want to buy and sell at the mid rather than the market.

Comment: Should get filled if the market moves the other way. aka, sell order will trigger when market goes up. And of course someone has to buy it then at your mid price. You might want to check "SNAP MID", but that is not in the API. I'm not sure if it will be picked up by tws. A Snap to Midpoint BUY order snaps to the midpoint of the bid/ask minus the offset to set the order price. For a SELL order, it snaps to the midpoint of the bid/ask plus the offset.